# GCP GKE - Healthcheck for native GKE ingress for the same application with 2 exposed ports

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application that is supposed to expose 2 x ports and the application does not have the default healthcheck endpoint of `/` that returns `200`, so at the moment, I supply a custom healthcheck endpoint just for 1 port. I haven't exposed the other port yet as I don't know how to provide another custom healthcheck endpoint for the same application.

This is how my Terraform configuration looks like.

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "core" {
  metadata {
    name = "core"
    labels = {
      app = "core"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "core"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "core"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          name = "core"
          image = "asia.gcr.io/admin/core:${var.app_version}"

          port {
            container_port = 8069
          }

          readiness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/web/database/selector"
              port = "8069"
            }
            initial_delay_seconds = 15
            period_seconds = 30
          }

          image_pull_policy = "IfNotPresent"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "core_service" {
  metadata {
    name = "core-service"
  }
  spec {
    type = "NodePort"
    selector = {
      app = "core"
    }
    port {
      port = 8080
      protocol = "TCP"
      target_port = "8069"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I tell GKE to expose the other port (8072) and use a custom healthcheck endpoint for both ports?

Answer (score 2):

There are a [GKE Ingress feature](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#configuring_ingress_features) called `FrontendConfig` and `BackendConfig` [custom resource definitions (CRDs)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) that allow you to further customize the load balancer, you can use a [Unique BackendConfig per Service port](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#unique_backendconfig_per_service_port) to specify a custom `BackendConfig` for a specific port or ports of a Service or `MultiClusterService`, using a key that matches the port's name or port's number. The Ingress controller uses the specific `BackendConfig` when it creates a load balancer backend service for a referenced Service port

When using a `BackendConfig` to provide a [custom load balancer health check](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#direct_health), the port number you use for the load balancer's health check can differ from the Service's `spec.ports[].port` number, here's an example of the service and the custom health check:

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
annotations:
cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {
"service-reference-a":"backendconfig-reference-a",
"service-reference-b":"backendconfig-reference-b"
}}'
spec:
  ports:
  - name: port-name-1
     port: port-number-1
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 50000
  - name: port-name-2
     port: port-number-2
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 8080
```

Custom Health Check:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
name: my-backendconfig
 spec:
    healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: interval
    timeoutSec: timeout
    healthyThreshold: health-threshold
    unhealthyThreshold: unhealthy-threshold
    type: protocol
    requestPath: path
    port: port
```

Comment: how can we create these custom health checks using terraform?  I've read this is not supported now, but is there any workaround for doing this?